# PHP How to SUM time data from Mysql

Tags: php

I want to SUM total Time from Each Vehicle

```
Date        End Time
BMW120
2014-03-03  01:53:48
2014-03-03  01:54:28
2014-03-03  01:58:08
2014-03-03  01:59:08
2014-03-03  02:00:08
Mercy123
2014-03-03  01:55:08
2014-03-03  01:55:28
2014-03-03  01:55:48
2014-03-03  01:58:28
Mitsubishi
2014-03-03  01:54:08
2014-03-03  01:54:48
2014-03-03  01:56:08
2014-03-03  01:56:28
```

i modify the vehicle to show only once in foreach loop
but now how to SUM Total time Each vehicle_id and Each Date 
Should i store in Array but how ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which DB is used ?

Comment: can you show some of your tried and failed code clips so that it would help us to know exactly what you want to add

Comment: where is the custom_id? do u have this as an array?

Comment: Which DB ? it's mysql,,, it's fixed before the table is not arrange

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total directly from database. You can use something like this to find out sum as seconds

```
SELECT custom_id, Date, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(EndTime)) AS totalTime
FROM your_table GROUP BY Date, custom_id
```

or you can use this to get it in HH:MM:SS format

```
SELECT custom_id, Date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(EndTime))) AS totalTime
FROM your_table GROUP BY Date, custom_id
```

Comment: What is your mysql version? it works for me in 5.0.96.

Comment: no because i have any other group 
SELECT latitude, longitude, COUNT(latitude) as lat, MIN(time), MAX(time)
,TIMEDIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time)) AS duration,  v.`name`,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`time`))) total,
 mobile_address, MAX(create_at) FROM tcm_packet p
INNER JOIN tcm_vehicles v ON p.mobile_address = v.gps_mobile_address
GROUP by latitude,longitude, mobile_address, DATE(create_at)
ORDER BY DATE(create_at),mobile_address DESC;

Comment: I see you have got a pretty complicated query there... Sorry I can't figure out what you are trying to do here. The query I gave was based on the fact that you already have the times and you want to sum them up. I guess that is not working for you.